# Text size too small on mobile optimised site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, optimization

I have made a website using bootstrap, it works well on desktop but on mobile the text size shrinks to very small, any solutions to make text appear well on mobile site?

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
         <img src="dapp/theme/images/hidden_superpower.jpg"alt="125x125">
          <h4>Your name's Hidden meaning!</h4>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 Media Rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body div a h4 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Or if your using SASS, change the value of the variables.